# Как можно получить access token другого пользователя vk

Tags: python, вконтакте

Делаю чат-бота вконтакте на языке Python. Недавно захотел добавить в бота одну функцию, но для этой функции надо иметь access_token юзера, который прислал сообщение. Есть вариант попросить пользователя перейти по ссылке (типо [вот такой](https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6684172&display=page&redirect_uri=http://vk.com/im-165897409&scope=wall,offline&response_type=token&v=5.52&state=123456)) и попросить отослать в сообщении полученный токен. Но это очень долго и заморочено.

В чём собственно вопрос: а можно ли сделать так, чтобы пользователь переходил по ссылке, нажимал "разрешить", и потом токен автоматически отправлялся мне? Если такая возможность есть, то просьба написать как это можно сделать на Python.

P.S. У меня есть рабочий сервер на flask, т.к. бот на callback api.

Comment: Конечно есть могу дать если надо?

Answer (score 3):

В ссылке для авторизации в качестве адреса редиректа нужно указать адрес своего сервера (например `redirect_uri=http://my_server.ru/callback`), после авторизации пользователя по этому адресу придет GET-запрос с указанием токена пользователя такого вида:

```
http://my_server.ru/callback?code=7a6fa4dff77a228eeda56603b8f...
```

На стороне сервера вам нужно будет этот запрос обработать.

Документация: [Authorization Code Flow для получения ключа доступа пользователя](https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user)